# AJAX authentication?

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, jsp, cordova

Pls see image http://whatcodecraves.com/images/backbonejs-auth-http.png,

I have 2 AJAX requests:

1. The first one  to authenticate, server responded:

   `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=06AB56403C08AD373BEDE33CBEFBE102; Path=/`
2. Another one to use the session. What should I do with this to send to server to use the same authentication session (a GET request)?

My code:

1. First AJAX Request:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url : "https://www.hafiz.gov.sa/HRDFWeb/AuthenticateDirectly",
       type : "POST",
       data : {
           "date" : "135854809",
           "json" : JSON.stringify({
               "nin" : "1089194383",
               "password" : "255793"
           })
       },
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Second AJAX Request:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url : 'https://www.hafiz.gov.sa/HRDFWeb/UpdateLastLogin?nin=1089194383&password=255793&date=1374661464&callback=?',
       type : "get",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       },
       error : function(data){
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
   ```

**EDIT:**

@w4rumy, Thanks for your answer, but I can't access that code. I'm writing a phonegap android app, this is the code that it uses to connect to server.

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.hafiz.gov.sa/HRDFWeb/AuthenticateDirectly");

List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", System.currentTimeMillis() + ""));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", "{\"nin\":\""+idd+"\",\"password\":\""+passs+"\"}"));

try {
    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
entity = response.getEntity();

Log.v("mytag", "Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());

if (entity != null) {
    try {
        entity.consumeContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Log.v("mytag", "Post logon cookies:");
cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
    Log.v("mytag", "None");
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        Log.v("mytag", "- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
    }
}

httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.hafiz.gov.sa/HRDFWeb/UpdateLastLogin?nin=1089194383&password=255793&date=1358448809");
try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How is this different from you [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874290/set-cookie-jsessionid-with-javascript)?

Comment: @w4rumy when i log in by using web page https://www.hafiz.gov.sa/HRDFWeb/index.html?# and run second ajax, it has the line "Cookie:JSESSIONID=78B61DEBA621A82376B5D7D10A1183F3; NSC_Ibgja-IUUQt=ffffffffc3a0b60045525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a0" on request header(you can use chrome or firefox to see it) and return value. I don't know why?

Comment: Anyway, 500 is a server error. So you should contact the person who made the server-side code.